# Add application to Privacy >> Accessibility in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

For enabling some of my application's features, I need the user to add the application in the accessibility list:
[image]

I understand this is not possible to do it without any user interaction, but at least I would like to know two things:

- How to know if the application is already in this list or not?
- If application does not yet belong to the list, how to display this dialog:
  [image]

I am using the last version of XCode and Objective-C. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions) returns whether the current process is a trusted accessibility client. Option kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt indicates whether the dialog will be displayed.